# How to copy a file content and append to another file with time delay?

Tags: python

I want to copy a file content and append it to another file line by line with a time gap of 2 seconds. Here is my code

```
#/usr/bin/python
import time
a=1
with open("input.txt") as f:
    fileoutput = f.readlines()
with open("output.txt", "a+") as f1:
    for line in fileoutput:
        f1.write(line)
        print(line)
        print"lines copied "+str(a)
        a=a+1
        time.sleep(2)
```

My goal is to append a line per 2 seconds to the output file. But my output file is not growing by time, means my code is not appending it to the output file, what changes do I need to do?

Comment: You should have just one `with` with two file pointers. Why 2 seconds delay(just curious). The first file might have been closed while executing the second with. so  do something like `with open('file_1') as f1 and open('file_2') as f2`

Comment: I think the problem is that the file will only update when it is flushed by Python, either by exiting the `with` block, calling `f1.flush()`, or calling `f1.close()` and not using `with`. I'll try to write up an example.

Comment: The code seems fine to me, maybe your text editor that you are using to view the output.txt file is not updating as the file itself changes (i.e. it loads the file once upon being opened and then does not check if the file has changed meanwhile whilst you have the file open).

Comment: @qwerty12345 I checked output.txt file using tailf command, but there was nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#/usr/bin/python
import time
a=1
with open("input.txt") as f:
    fileoutput = f.readlines()
with open("output.txt", "a+") as f1:
    for line in fileoutput:
        f1.write(line)
        f1.flush()
        print(line)
        print"lines copied "+str(a)
        a=a+1
        time.sleep(2)
```

All you need to do is add [`f1.flush()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_flush) to ensure that the file is updated after each write, rather than at the end of the `with` block.